# Deleted destructor in the class appeared as a virtual/direct base class or as a type of non-static data member

Tags: c++

There is a rule about cases when the copy/move constructor is implicitly deleted:

> An implicitly-declared copy/move constructor is an inline public
>   member of its class. A defaulted copy/ move constructor for a class X
>   is defined as deleted (8.4.3) if X has:
>
> [...]
>
> — any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member of a type
>   with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted
>   constructor, or
>
> [...]

Because I can't find an example reflecting the rule, it's not clear to me. Consider the following code:

```
struct A
{
    ~A() = delete;
};

struct B : A
{
    A a;
    B(){ }; //error error: attempt to use a deleted function B(){ };
    B(const B&&)  = delete;
};

B *b = new B;

int main() { }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3f024c510315f46)**

Because of deleted move constructor doesn't take a part in overload resolution, I expected the error would be something like "Copy constructor is implicitly deleted". But instead I got the error about deleted `B()`, which I defined explicitly. Couldn't you provide an example reflecting that rule?

Comment: "deleted move constructor doesn't take a part in overload resolution" - that applies only to a defaulted move constructor that is defined as deleted. It doesn't apply to explicitly deleted move constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Based only on the excerpt you've provided, the following is an example:

```
struct inner
{
    ~inner() = delete;
};

struct outer
{
    inner inst;

    // Can't destroy "inst"; outer now has an implicitly
    // deleted destructor and copy/move constructor.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at 5th point: it is clearly saying that you have deleted your base class dtor so you are having this problem.

link: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor

> **Deleted implicitly-declared default constructor**
>
> The implicitly-declared or defaulted default constructor for class T is undefined (until C++11)defined as deleted (since C++11) if any of the following is true:
>
> 1. T has a member of reference type without a brace-or-equal
>      initializer. (since C++11)
> 2. T has a const member without user-defined default constructor or a
>      brace-or-equal initializer (since C++11).
> 3. T has a member (without a brace-or-equal initializer) (since C++11),
>      which has a deleted default constructor, or its default constructor
>      is ambiguous or inaccessible from this constructor.
> 4. T has a direct or virtual base which has a deleted default
>      constructor, or it is ambiguous or inaccessible from this
>      constructor.
> 5. **T has a direct or virtual base which has a deleted destructor, or a
>      destructor that is inaccessible from this constructor.**
> 6. T is a union with at least one variant member with non-trivial
>      default constructor.
>          (since C++11)
> 7. T is a union and all of its variant members are const.

Comment: But in my case defauolt constructor was declared implicitly.

Comment: that's what i am telling, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_default_constructor). And if this is not your answer then i am totally confuse, what are u looking for?

Comment: `B()` is not an implicitly-declared default constructor, in the question.

Comment: you commented it but why i didn't feel to comment it, though i also found the same problem in his comment `But in my case defauolt constructor was declared implicitly`, may be i thought he dont want to understand, or drastically confuse with his own things.